# Can I change a form control value but not trigger an event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

This one may be hard to ask but I will do my best.  Lots of stuff on SO and elsewhere on making an event trigger on change but I want the opposite (at least I think I do!).

I have several controls on a form (`numericUpDowns`).  For each updown, I'm watching to see if a value has been changed and it will trigger a "ValueChanged" method.

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do some complicated code ...
}
```

It's all working well with the changes to up-down controls causing recalculation of the fomr BUT what if I want to set a few of the values in a method and NOT call my `ValueChanged` melthods until the end?

I'd almost like something like this

```
// start ignoring form events here
numericUpDown1.Value = 500;
numericUpDown2.Value = 50;
numericUpDown3.Value = 0;
// resume detecting form events here !
```

Is there a way to turn this on and off?  is it something that I should worry about?

The best thing my limited C# knowledge leads me to a this point is to create a variable called "`bIgnoreEvents`" and use it in each of my `ValueChanged` Methods ...

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bIgmoreEvents)
    {
        //do some complicated code ...
    }
}
```

this would skip the code but seems messy.  Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why do you think it's messy? It would do the job just fine and in a straight, understandable and maintainable way, assuming you meant `if (!bIgnoreEvents)`.

Comment: Thanks, Magically fixed now .)  Okay, perhaps not "messy" maybe just not elegant ... as I'm fairly new to this I'm quite often worried of picking up bad habits ...

Comment: Well, there's a very fine line between elegance and less-readable cleverness, and since you're new to this I would suggest not aiming that way (at least not at first). Instead, focus on getting something that works while being as simple and understandable as possible. Follow the [KISS principle](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/kiss.html).

Comment: ignoring the input in your event handler will be the simplest approach.

Comment: Thanks!  Now, what do I do in S.O. with this question? Delete it?  There is not really a "no answer required" button ...

Comment: You could write your own answer and save it for posterity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also do this:

```
var eventHandler = new EventHandler((o, a) =>
{
    //do stuff
});

numericUpDown1.ValueChanged += eventHandler;

//normal behaviour

//remove eventHandler    
numericUpDown1.ValueChanged -= eventHandler;

numericUpDown1.Value = 500;
numericUpDown2.Value = 50;
numericUpDown3.Value = 0;

//add eventHandler
numericUpDown1.ValueChanged += eventHandler;
```

Comment: Is this still the broadly accepted way to prevent the event? [by removing and then re-adding after the 'triggering' action] Just seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Haha I don't know, this was 6 years ago :) it probably still works. But shouldn't an event handle any changes for the thing even if the user didn't do them?